# Error out of Package If Not Following Specific Design

Tags: sql-server, csv, ssis, etl, flat-file

So I've encountered an interesting situation with importing a flat text file (using commas as a delimiter) into a table in my DB

The file is really very simple and the only reason I caught this strange situation was because I wanted to test out some error logging tid bits if the package failed.

When trying to purposely crash my package, I took my text file and started putting in random commas in places they shouldn't be and creating random headers that weren't initially defined.  Strangely enough they all imported without issue!

The approved file that should be going through and importing into the system looks something like this

```
Col1, Col2, Col3
Data1, Data2, Data3
...
```

The agreed upon file should ALWAYS be 3 columns with all columns currently being Strings.

When I tried to break my package by doing some of the following

```
Col1, Col2, Col3, TESTBREAKHDR
Data1, Data2, Data3
...

Col1, Col2, Col3
Data1, Data2, Data3, TESTBREAKDATA
...
```

The header was simply disregarded and the data shifted over and was concatenated into the last row.

To me these are errors I want to catch and NOT proceed to do any kind of import.  Since these files are being generated somewhere else and just being picked up by my package for consumption - rather than trying to fix the file before hand (since some investigative work will need to be done prior to fixing) - I want it to simply error out and not proceed with any importing.

Any helpful tips or pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

When adding extra columns in the header, if you are using a `Flat File Source` to read from the `Flat File Connection Manager`, when package is executed. The `Flat File Source` will throw an exception, alerting you that metadata needs to be updated and that validation is failed.

When extra columns are found in data rows. you can Add a script component in the Data Flow Task, and for each row check if `Col3`  contains commas `,`. If so throw exception.

The extra information in rows will not throw error on validation only if the data length of column is exceeded.

*Note: as you said, the flat file connection manager doesn't detect extra columns in data rows, it will concatenate them in the last column*